# Stripping 0's from the middle of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically data is coming into my program in this format
0xxxx000xxxx where the x is unique to the data that I have in another system. I'm trying to remove those 0's as they're always in the same place.
I tried

```
df['item'] = df['item'].str.replace('0','')
```

but sometimes the x can be a 0 and will get rid of it. I'm not sure how to get rid of just the 0's in those specific positions.

EX:
Input: 099890000890

Output (Desired): 99890890

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor for indexing:

```
df['item'] = df['item'].str[1:5] + df['item'].str[8:]
```

Or [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['item'] = df['item'].str.replace(r'0(.{4})000(.{4})', r'\1\2', regex=True)
```

Output (as new column. Item2):

```
           item     item2
0  099890000890  99890890
```

Comment: This was perfect. Turns out changing the datatype to a string removed the leading 0, so I just had to change the first limit to str[0,4].

Comment: I added another approach

Comment: "changing the datatype to a string removed the leading 0" No; if the data wasn't already a string, then *the leading 0 wasn't there to begin with* - integer types **don't have digits**, and thus cannot represent leading zeroes. If you are reading data from a file, for example, make sure to tell Pandas to treat that column as string data, rather than inferring a type. Since the non-stripped digits can sometimes be zero as well, you will run into problems if you try to treat this data as numeric *at any step in the process*.